# SVG cause a row of errors thrown in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, svg

A static page with pure `JS` and `HTML` and a svg file inserted in an "object" tag, everything is fine, but in one point I have noticed a stack of errors in the console. Everything works, but anyway I would like to understand the origin of it.

I tried to move file, clear cache, attaching svg using `JS` code at the end of page load, removing all of `JS` leaving file in pure `HTML`, removing reference to the `CSS` file in the svg itself, the error is always the same and it doesn't show only when the svg is out.

Google Chrome Version `38.0.2125.58 beta` on linux peppermint os three,
I didn't noticed anything like that in FF and I didn't test other browsers. Greetings

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
Stack trace: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at initialize (chrome-extension://mdgdbmohcdjfbglkepkiaabaieenhhhc/inject.js:367:16)
    at handleMessage (chrome-extension://mdgdbmohcdjfbglkepkiaabaieenhhhc/inject.js:58:5)
    at EventImpl.dispatchToListener (extensions::event_bindings:397:22)
    at Event.publicClass.(anonymous function) [as dispatchToListener] (extensions::utils:93:26)
    at EventImpl.dispatch_ (extensions::event_bindings:379:35)
    at EventImpl.dispatch (extensions::event_bindings:403:17)
    at Event.publicClass.(anonymous function) [as dispatch] (extensions::utils:93:26)
    at dispatchOnMessage (extensions::messaging:304:22)             extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:9
handler                         extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:9
exports.handle                         extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:15
EventImpl.dispatch_                     extensions::event_bindings:384
EventImpl.dispatch                      extensions::event_bindings:403
target.(anonymous function)             extensions::SafeBuiltins:19
publicClass.(anonymous function)        extensions::utils:93
dispatchOnMessage                     extensions::messaging:304
```

Comment: Have you tried this in an incognito window?

Comment: Try disabling the "Word Translator" / "PIE" extension and see if it goes away.

Comment: No errors in incognito, and yes, that's the translator.

Comment: Thanx for your points guys, give it as a regular answer so I'll close the thread and throw some reputation at you.